# R: Problems with an "if" condition

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, vector

I am dealing with the following problem, I have two vectors namely:

```
index1<-c(10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,16 ,17 ,18 ,19 ,20 ,21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29)

index2<-c(17 ,18, 19, 20 ,22 ,23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 ,31 ,32, 33 ,42, 43, 44,45, 46 ,47 ,48, 49, 50, 51, 52 ,53, 54 ,55, 56)
```

I want to keep all the components `index2[j]` that can be written as `2*index1[i]+k` where `k=0,1,2,3`. for some `i in 1:length(index1),j in 1:length(index2)`

This is, for instance the first component of index2 is 17, and this cannot be written as `2*index1[i]+k` so this first component should be deleted (or replaced with a NA).
I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to do that, I've tried to do a loop but without success.

```
for(j in 1:length(index2)){
  for(i in 1:length(index1)){
    for(k in 0:3){
if (index2[j]!=(2*index1[i]+k)){index2[j]=NA}else{index2[j]=index2[j]}}}}
```

In this particular example the output desired is a vector `index2_refined` which contains all components of `index2` with exception of the first one, i.e.

```
c( 20 ,22 ,23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 ,31 ,32, 33 ,42, 43, 44,45, 46 ,47 ,48, 49, 50, 51, 52 ,53, 54 ,55, 56)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what's the desired output for this particular example so that possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Comment: Hi, sorry but 18 cannot be written as 2*index1[i]+k too correct?

Comment: You are right I messed up things, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ok` consists of all values of `2*index1[i]+k` so if `index2[j]` is not found in `ok` then NA it out:

```
ok <- outer(2*index1, 0:3, `+`)
replace(index2, ! (index2 %in% ok), NA)
```

Alternately, to only keep the elements found in `ok`:

```
index2[index2 %in% ok]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea withou the `for()`:

```
library(dplyr)
index1.1 = unique(2*rep(index1,4) + c(rep(1,length(index1)),rep(2,length(index1)),rep(3,length(index1)),rep(4,length(index1))))

index2[index2 %in% index1.1]
[1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56
```

Also, as Paolo pointed out, acording to your logic the first 4 elements should be removed

Comment: I get your point even though the extra term `k` goes from `0:3`